# USB 3.0 not recognising USB stick?

Tags: usb, usb-3

I built myself a PC using the Asus P8H61-MX USB3 motherboard. It has 2x USB 3.0 ports on it. I plugged my USB sticks in and nothing happened. I plugged them into normal USB ports on the same motherboard and it worked. I checked in the BIOS and USB 3.0 is enabled.

I looked on the Microsoft website and MS say:

"Make sure to use a USB 3.0 port for USB 3.0 devices. Otherwise, you can use the most convenient port available."

So does this mean USB 3.0 ports don't let you use a USB stick that isn't USB 3.0? If they don't, that's fine! Just want to be sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use legacy usb devices in usb3 ports no problem. perhaps the driver isn't installed in windows? (windows 7 and lower won't recognize the usb3 ports until you install the corresponding drivers)

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, It was a driver issue in the end. I used the CD that came with the motherboard and found a driver called 'Asmedia USB 3.0 Driver'. Installed and works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! I'd really appreciate an upvote on the comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you re-check. I see your motherboard did **not** have any USB 3.0 port include http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H61MX/#specifications

I guess maybe your PC-case did have support USB 3.0 on it, but because your motherboard not. So these port might **not (or forgot) connected to your motherboard**  which cause there port will not work.

For more information: USB 3.0 is compatible backward to USB 2.0 so if you plug-in any device, it should work.

---

update: Your motherboard have 2 USB3.0 port at at **back panel**, and do not have any to connect to font panel. So, it can be true that your USB3.0 port on your case is **not connect** to anywhere

Comment: Hi Hardy, there seems to be a few variants of the motherboard. This is mine: http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H61MX_USB3/#specifications

Comment: you mention 'Asus P8H61-MX' in your question, please update to 'P8H61-MX USB3' :)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this by installing the USB 3.0 driver from the CD that came with the motherboard. I didn't know USB 3.0 needed a driver to become backwards compatible with USB 2.0 Thanks.